# SQL Is there a way to use Lower with out a full table scan

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm currently using lower() function in my SQL.

As per this thread, using lower() on a column will cause a full table scan: 
[Avoid full table scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332455/avoid-full-table-scan)

Is there a way to prevent this or minimise the impact of the scan? I'm using Oracle 10.

My Sql:

```
select * from USER u where lower(u.USERNAME) = lower(?)
```

Comment: how about creating a functional index on `lower()` ?

Comment: How about an extra column storing the lowercase version? Or if you never care about case you can turn case sensitivity off.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case insensitive searching in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle)

Comment: @Barmar, I don't see how its a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko The obvious purpose of the comparison in his question is to perform a case-insensitive match.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the link. This question is based more around different ways to prevent a full table scan knowing how to do a case-insensitive match. While that question is based more around how to do a case-insensitive scan.

Comment: One answer did make mention of function based index, I'm also interested in other ways aside from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you always search using low cases, you can create an index on the case-lowered Username, like I did in this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17990/1).

Here the syntax from my demo:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
    (username varchar2(4))
;

CREATE INDEX t1_idx ON t1(lower(username));
```

Comment: It would be better to include the syntax to do that, not just link to it; this answer isn't much use if SQL Fiddle is down (or blocked). A [link to the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5012.htm#sthref4484) for function-based indexes wouldn't hurt either for some background.

Comment: @AlexPoole you are right, I have edited my answer to include the code